# R sum elements of list without getting numeric(0)

Tags: r, list

I want to sum all the elements of a list.

```
mylist <- c(1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0)
mylistempty <- list()
mylist2 <- c(0,0,0,0)

Reduce('+', mylist)
```

but when you do reduce on an empty list of a list that only contains `0` then you get a `numeric(0)`
I want to do the same as `sum()` does, but with a list.

Comment: `mylist` and `mylist2` are not lists but vectors, pick one.

Comment: Maybe you mean `mylistempty <- numeric()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These should work and return `0` for empty objects:

```
 sum(a_vector)
 do.call(sum, a_list)
 sum(unlist(a_list_or_a_vector))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Reduce` function (possibly because you really do want to sum a list of vectors) then just set the `init` argument to 0 (or another appropriate object).